# how to compare a value at a position in a char array input by the user with an integer value

Tags: c, arrays, char

If I input a large integer value in a character array in c then how can I compare the value at every position of the char array with  an integer

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, paying special attention to the concept of MCVE.

Comment: "*If I input*" how? "*a larger integer value*" how large? "*... at every position ...*" "*every*"?

Answer (score -1):

That makes limited sense.

I believe what you're asking is "how can I convert a string from the user into an integer, so I can compare it to another integer"?

If so, then there are several ways. One good way is by using [`strtoul()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul):

```
unsigned long x = strtoul("1234", NULL, 10);
if(x == 1234)
{
  printf("something wonderful has happened\n");
}
```

If the value is so "large" so that it doesn't fit in a C integer type, then it becomes harder, but you're not being very clear. Converting the reference number to string and then comparing the two strings might be possible, but that assumes you can work with the reference integer (which might be hard if it too is too big).